# Modx revo does not compare date type TV in getResourses

Tags: mysql, date, modx, getresource

I'm trying to compare date from TV with date from snippet ( i'm using &tvFilters) (or any other date string) but works only == and != operations? but i need to make >= and <=, what's wrong? examples say that it's must work, can it be some MYSQL problem? looks like it's compares like strings...

```
[[!getResources? &showHidden=`1`  &processTVs=`1` &includeTVs=`1` 
 &tpl=`rotatorPost` &includeContent=`1` &parents=`5` &limit=`3` 
&tvFilters=`Date>=2016-01-19 00:00:00` ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to make sure both dates are converted to unix timestamps [the TV probably already is] 
You will have to retrieve your TV "Date" either unprocessed [&processTVs=`0`] or set it's output type to numeric. 
Your snippet will have to provide the date as a numeric type as well.

In any case, you will have to check to docs to make sure getResources will not treat either value as a stringor else:

&tvFilters=`1453239348 >= 1453239399` is going to give you unexpected results.

though the docs look good in that respect:

> New filter operators available in 1.4.2-pl  Starting with release
>   1.4.2-pl of getResources, there are a number of new comparison operators for use when creating filter conditions. In addition, when
>   using many of these new operators, numeric comparison values are
>   automatically CAST TV values to numeric before comparison. Here is a
>   list of the valid operators: